# Creating table layout and adding rows from the code behind in Android

Tags: android, code-behind, android-tablelayout

I need to create a table layout and add rows dynamically from Java code behind. I have already read questions here, but they are mentioning to add table rows in an already created table layout (from xml).

I need to create the table layout as well as add data to it dynamically.
Can anyone please provide some inputs?

For now, I have linear layout code in place which adds button from code behind one below the other, I need to place it under a tabular format now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add three buttons to TableRow use the code below

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("1");
        tableRow.addView(button);

        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("2");
        tableRow.addView(button);

        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("3");
        tableRow.addView(button);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
    setContentView(tableLayout);
```

Comment: You can add a for loop to add 3 buttons

Comment: I did some modifications as per my requirement and I was good to go... Thanks for helping me out.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the code below to your `onCreate()` method in you `Activity` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(""+j);
            tableRow.addView(button);
        }

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
    setContentView(tableLayout);
}
```

The code will add five rows with three buttons with the text 1 to 3 to the table.

Comment: Won't Layout parameters be used while coding GUI dynamically...?? Just asking out of curiosity...

Also, what if I want to add buttons in such a way that I must have 3 columns in each row?

Comment: Yes you can use TableLayout.LayoutParams. and if you want a row ith 3 columns just add 3 views to the table row

Comment: Can you please be more specific..?? for adding 3 views to the row...? Because I would be adding each button in each iteration of the loop.. so couldn't add 3 views simultaneously. Could you please explain with an example?

Comment: Check the answe below

Comment: @HussainChachuliya copy the code and replace your Activities onCreate method with it

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code below your `init()` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GetGlobal.totalrow; i++) {
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
            // tbrow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
            TextView t1v = new TextView(this);

            t1v.setText(JSONParser.heading[i].replace('"', ' '));
            t1v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.diamond_detail1);
            t1v.setPadding(5, 3, 5, 3);
            t1v.setMinHeight(50);
            t1v.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);
```